# Updating fIle path in MySQL through PHP does not work

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am storing network share paths in my table in MySQL. but some entries got corrupted, i.e they dont have any backslashes in between. Path is like a big word. 
I wrote a small script in PHP to update these paths to try and add slashes. It does not give me any error when I run it but the results are not getting updated in the table.

Currently the path in my tables is like this:
    `\fil01logsTestDat1oop_s2010Log`
and I want to make it 
    `\\fil01\logs\Test\Dat1\oop_s\2010\Log`

If I echo the last `$ch7` the results is what I want but it is not going into the table.

```
$result = mysql_query("select dbresultsid,ResultDirectory from results where dbresultsid > 48717") or die(mysql_error());  
$i= 0;
// store the record of the "example" table into $row
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

$ch = $row['ResultDirectory'];
$id  = $row['dbresultsid'];


if(strstr($ch, $fsd))
{
//echo 'Yes'.$i.'<br>';
//$i++;
$ch1 = str_replace("fil01","\\fil01\\",$ch);
$ch2 = str_replace("logs","logs\\",$ch1);
$ch3 = str_replace("Test","Test\\",$ch2);
$ch4 = str_replace("Dat1","Dat1\\",$ch3);
$ch5 = str_replace("oop_s","oop_s\\",$ch4);
$ch6 = str_replace("2010","2010\\",$ch5);
$ch7 = str_replace("Log","\\Log",$ch6);
//echo trim($ch7).'<br>';
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("opp") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Updating $id with $ch7 <br>";
$update_again = mysql_query("update results set ResultDirectory = \"$ch7\" where dbresultsid = \"$id\" ") or die(mysql_error());  
echo "Updated record $i <br>";
$i++;
}

}

?>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Print the update query, run it and see what happens.

Comment: printing?, I am printing the results again, but I don't see any update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved. The only setting I had to make was this :

`$set = mysql_query("set sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';");`

before updating.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is in most environments an [**escape character**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). You've basically two solutions:

1. Use double backslash `\\` to *represent* a single backslash.
2. Use forward slashes `/` instead (works perfectly in all platforms, including Windows and *NIX).

I would prefer solution 2 as it works everywhere and would minimize developer confusion.

Comment: I couldn't understand your suggestion for / ?

Comment: Instead of `\\fil01\logs\Test\Dat1\oop_s\2010\Log`, you could have it `fil01/logs/Test/Dat1/oop_s/2010/Log`

Comment: @JPro: no, you are using it to escape \ in PHP code itself. You need to escape it once more for MySQL, so your PHP string should look like `foo\\\\bar\\\\waa`. Optionally you can also configure the environment so that it doesn't eat them (as you found out with `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`). With my suggestion for forward slahes I just **literally** mean to use them **instead of** backslashes. Replace them by forward slashes. `foo/bar/waa`. That's all. It works in all platforms and you don't need to hassle with environmental behaviours and configs wrt backslashes which may make your code unportable.